# Creating a new user scope in an app registration in Entra ID using the Graph REST API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-app-registration, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to create a new user scope for an existing app registration in Entra ID using the Graph REST API. It's one of those scopes that appear under oauth2Permissions in the manifest. This is not mentioned anywhere in the docs and the GraphApiClient class in .NET does not seem to support a way to do it either. It fails when sending this request.

```
    PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{applicationId}
Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "oauth2Permissions": [
        {
            "adminConsentDescription": "Read access to user profiles",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read user profiles",
            "id": "some-guid",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "type": "User",
            "userConsentDescription": "Read access to your user profile",
            "userConsentDisplayName": "Read your user profile",
            "value": "User.Read"
        },
        // Add or update other permissions as needed
    ]
}
```

I'm getting an error. oauth2Permissions is not supported. What's the correct way to get that updated ?

Comment: Hi, i guess you  should use the appRole property instead of oauth2Permissions in the application manifest.

Comment: No, this is not an app role. I can create app roles just fine with the API. This is an user scope, not a role. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create new **user scope** in an app registration in Entra ID using Graph API, make use of below PATCH request:

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{appObjId}
Authorization: Bearer <your-access-token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "api": {
        "oauth2PermissionScopes": [
            {
                "adminConsentDescription": "Read access to user profiles",
                "adminConsentDisplayName": "Read user profiles",
                "id": "some-guid",
                "isEnabled": true,
                "type": "User",
                "userConsentDescription": "Read access to your user profile",
                "userConsentDisplayName": "Read your user profile",
                "value": "User.Read"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where new scope added successfully in application like this:

[image]

You can now find these details in application's **`Manifest`** tab as below:

[image]

Comment: This works great. How did you find out about that "api" element ? It's not documented anywhere. Thanks

Comment: See the Microsoft Graph reference documentation for the **[application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-1.0)** resource type, and from there, see the **[apiApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/apiapplication?view=graph-rest-1.0)** resource.